# Opencart selected link has a class

Tags: php, opencart

So I have a class selected, which should only be active when you are on the page of the link you pressed, and I am trying to get it in the code with php and asking if the current page is equal to any of the links and the one link that is equal should get the class.

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
   <div class="menu col-sm-5 noPadding">
   <?php foreach ($categories as $category) {
      $url = "http://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
      $isIt = $category['href']; ?> 
      <?php if ($url == $isIt){ ?>
         <a class="selected" href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php } else  { ?>
         <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
       <?php } ?>        
   <?php } ?>
   </div>  
<?php } ?>
```

This is all in opencart and I would like to continue using foreach instead of having to code every link in by itself.
I've tried echoing them out and I get exactly the same things written.

Ok so this is the output from var_dump($categories)

```
array (size=4)
  'name' => string 'Desktops' (length=8)
  'children' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'column' => string '1' (length=1)
  'href' => string 'http://localhost/openC/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=20' (length=67)
1 => 
array (size=4)
  'name' => string 'Components' (length=10)
  'children' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'column' => string '1' (length=1)
  'href' => string 'http://localhost/openC/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=25' (length=67)
2 => 
array (size=4)
  'name' => string 'Cameras' (length=7)
  'children' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'column' => string '1' (length=1)
  'href' => string 'http://localhost/openC/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=33' (length=67)
3 => 
array (size=4)
  'name' => string 'MP3 Players' (length=11)
  'children' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'column' => string '4' (length=1)
  'href' => string 'http://localhost/openC/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=34' (length=67)
```

Comment: Please post output of `var_dump($categories)`.

Comment: @JánKyselica added it to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php if ($categories) { 
    $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?> 
    <div class="menu col-sm-5 noPadding">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>     
       <?php if ($url == html_entity_decode($category['href'])){ ?>
          <a class="selected" href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
       <?php } else  { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
       <?php } ?>        
   <?php } ?>
   </div>  
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: http://localhost/openC/index.php?route=common/home this is the echo with http at the beginning it doesnt show here

Comment: The code I posted above is maybe working, because you compare category URL `http://localhost/openC/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=25` with Home page URL `http://localhost/openC/index.php?route=common/home`. On the Home page you haven't selected any category. You must try this code on the category page.

Comment: I know on the homepage there shouldnt be anything selected I am trying it on the other pages and the URLs are correct but nothing is selected

Comment: And if you open `http://localhost/openC/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=25` is some category selected?

Comment: I opened every category that I have and nothing is selected anywhere

Comment: What is output of `echo $url;` on that category page?

Comment: I found out the problem, they always output `&amp;` instead of the & sign so they didnt matchup I made a solution not so perfect but it solved the problem, anyways, thanks for the help :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I edited my answer for decoding html entities. You can try it.